# Advise on renaming a Android project in Android studio(Gradle based)

Tags: android, android-studio

In my present project , I wish to rename the Android project in Android studio (0.8.9) and wish to use it hereafter. I know about 2 solutions discussed in forum. Could some one please confirm best approach and hassle free. Moreover any advice tried/tested on Android studio 0.8.9 is best.

Solutions I know about (but not sure)
A.- Close the project under consideration.Copy it and rename to new name and open with Android studio.
 In this case - The project .iml file still shows the old name and so does the .name file under ".idea" folder.
I also get this error:

**Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: . Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.**

B. Using F6 option ,but it does not copy. I think it moves the entire project, which is not the solution.

Answer (score 16):

The following works for me when renaming the project:

- Close Android Studio
- Delete the *.iml file(s) in your project's root directory
- Delete everything in the .idea directory except [workspace.xml and tasks.xml](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067).
- Rename your project's root directory to the new project name
- Restart Android Studio and import the project from the renamed directory.

Note: If you don't care about losing your workspace settings (window sizes, etc.) and you don't have any tasks then you can just delete the .idea directory entirely.

Answer (score 5):

**In Android 1.5.1 tested and worked:**

1. Open Project folder (you could open it through Android studio itself see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33778304/5235263)
2. make sure Android Studio Is closed
3. change the yourOldProjectName.iml to the new name
4. rename the parent folder to same new name.
5. re-open Android Studio --> File --> Open--> path to your renamed.iml

Comment: This works for me in `version 2.1.2`. Not sure why `right click` -> `refactor` -> `rename` still doesn't work for the root module though...

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to solve this.

Open Android Studio, File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.