# open project folder from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know it is a trivial function, but is there an option in Android Studio to open project folder into a file explorer (from AS)?

p.s.
 It is always possible to navigate to the project folder, following path displayed on AS window header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found The answer myself: do as follow in Android studio

1. click the folder that you want to open in explorer (just click to get it highlighted)
2. right click --> Show In Explorer ! 
   [image]

Comment: What about a file that I located via shift shift?

Comment: This options is not always there. If you have the file open, you can just do shit-shift 'Reveal in Finder'

Answer (score 5):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>, or go to *Help->Find Action...* type `Reveal` and on Mac OS X you'll get "Reveal in Finder" action. On other operating systems the action may have different title but it should be there. You can also map a shortcut for that action in *Preferences->Keymap*.

Comment: You don't need to type 'Find action' first. You can do "Reveal directly" :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can simply click left mouse button on open file tab with Ctrl pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1) just open file in the editor, then rigth click -> Open In -> Explorer.

[image]